# Constructing Triangular Mesh for 3-Dimensional Data Surface Data in Python

Tags: python, 3d, mesh, triangular

I have a dataset of 3-dimensional points for which I'd like to construct a mesh, using python. All the software I've seen requires that you provide the edges. Is there a program in python which takes as the input a set of points in 3D and outputs a set of triangular meshes? If possible, I'd like the meshing to be uniform.

Thank you,
- Eli.

Comment: Are the points representing a surface or a volume?  I did this once with delaunay triangulation, but it first required projecting the points on a plane.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention for future reference that [scicomp.SE] is a good place for questions like this.

Comment: The points represent a surface. Did projection to a plane work well?

Answer (score 1):

If the points represent a surface, you can use Delaunay triangulation as suggested by @wim.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial
import pylab

data = np.random.random((12,3))            # arbitrary 3D data set
tri = scipy.spatial.Delaunay( data[:,:2] ) # take the first two dimensions

pylab.triplot( data[:,0], data[:,1], tri.simplices.copy() )
pylab.plot( data[:,0], data[:,1], 'ro' ) ;
```

[image: Delaunay triangulation]

From there, the triangles, or simplicies, are accessed through the `simplices` attribute of the `tri` object. For example, `tri.simplices[0]` refers to the first triangle, or simplex, and it returns an array of three integers, say, `[ 10, 0, 5 ]`. This means that the points making up the first simplex are found at indices, 10, 0, and 5, in the array, `data`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how easily you can use existing java libraries in python, but [Jzy3d](http://www.jzy3d.org/) may help you to generate meshes from points: there is an orthogonal tesselator for inputs based on  points standing on a regular grid, and a delaunay tesselator for an unknown point structures. (disclaimer: I'm the author)